# how to prevent user from change/delete button property in Developer tool

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In attached image button is disabled by default based on access, however if i delete the property highlighted it gets enabled & user can able to perform actions.

Please do provide solution to restrict it.

[Please see image attached related to issue with chrome Developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlCTj.jpg)

Comment: do your sanity checks on server side.

Comment: try using angular 4 or above. Its more complicated for end users to decode code of angular :)

Comment: i am using angularjs

Comment: @vibs2006 that's not good advice...security by obscurity is not real security. Someone with the relevant knowledge, but malicious intent, will soon work out what to do. You can't assume all the users have no experience of the codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop the user from doing that. Its their browser, and it's entirely in their control. Any user can manipulate the page in any way they choose, and run any script they choose from the console, etc etc. If the have the knowledge and inclination, they can do as they please. If they want to change the page to try and make a malicious or incorrect submission of they data, they can.

The mitigation you can (and must) put in place is to check and sanitise all data coming into your server-side API to guard against what is coming from the client being malicious or otherwise inappropriate.

Bear in mind your API just accepts HTTP requests, there's nothing to say a client even needs to use your web app to make requests, they could use a tool like PostMan or any other HTTP client to attack it. They can bypass the browser completely. So you have to apply all permissions, data checking etc on the server first to ensure security. If you then apply it on the browser-based web app, that's nice but you have to regard it as just a usability feature - it can never provide any real security.

Answer (score 0):

well, as all html code in the browser you cannot prevent it from being manipulated, never trust the client and check the access of this action in the backend.

Keep in mind that even if the button is disabled, a developer can rebuild the request of this form and send it without using any user interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way that you can do in this kind of situation. You must unbind the event when the button is disabled and bind it again when the button is enabled. It will solve your problem.

Much better sanitize it in server side.